# Best way to map a list to a Map of another trait

Tags: scala, dictionary, traits, for-comprehension

Lets say I have a `List[TraitA]` of objects. `TraitA` provides a property `propX : String`. 
I know that a subset of this list is also an instance of `TraitB`, which however does not provide the property `propX`.

So for example:

```
trait TraitA
{
  def propX : String
}

trait TraitB
{
  def abc : Int
}
```

Some of the instances in the list just `extend TraitA`, while others `extend TraitA with TraitB`. I need to extract only those instances which have `TraitB` but I need to retain the property `propX` from `TraitA`. `propX` can only be a few values, and what I need is a `Map` which groups the instances of `TraitB` according to this value.

So what I need to extract is this subset of `TraitB` instances from the `List[TraitA]` instances, since some of them are `TraitA with TraitB`, and create a `Map[String, List[TraitB]]`, where the key is `propX` from `TraitA`.

I have been fiddling around with `for` comprehensions but for some reason I can't `yield` a `List[(String, TraitB)]` of tuples (which I could then `groupBy _.1`), probably because the first generator is of type `TraitA`.

I tried this, but it complains that the expected type is `List[(String, TraitA)]`:

```
for {
traitA <- listOfTraitAs
traitBoption = (traitA match {
    case traitB : TraitB => Some(traitB)
    case _ => None
   })
} yield (traitA.propX, traitBoption)
```

On the other hand, if I `filter` the list by pattern matching on `TraitB` I lose visibility of `propX` in the filtering function.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can you give an example with real values to show how it should look like in the end?

Comment: Well its a bit difficult to paste the full scenario. I will try to clarify a bit more above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why `filter` does not work for you:

```
scala> trait TraitA { def propX: String }; trait TraitB { def abc: Int }
defined trait TraitA
defined trait TraitB

scala> class A extends TraitA { def propX = util.Random.nextInt(5).toString() }
defined class A

scala> class B extends A with TraitB { def abc = util.Random.nextInt(5) }
defined class B

scala> val xs: List[TraitA] = List.fill(15)(if (util.Random.nextBoolean()) new A else new B)
xs: List[TraitA] = List(A@6b46e91a, B@7c71e0fb, A@1869be91, B@465e2e1c, B@5125545b, A@69c54bfb, B@17ff81fd, A@7af155a, B@77a2cba6, A@60e83ca6, A@2ee5e7fe, B@77e1ecbf, A@117e2d16, A@72c20852, B@20b07a5a)

scala> xs collect { case a: TraitB => a } groupBy (_.propX)
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[TraitA with TraitB]] = Map(4 -> List(B@465e2e1c, B@77e1ecbf), 1 -> List(B@77a2cba6), 0 -> List(B@20b07a5a), 2 -> List(B@7c71e0fb, B@17ff81fd), 3 -> List(B@5125545b))
```

Even if you loose visibility, you can always do a pattern match with something like `{ case a: TraitA with TraitB => }`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that when you do something like `groupBy` you still had visibility on the old type! Thanks for that!